# IB Action Button not doing anything Cant understand why?

Tags: sqlite, ios-simulator, xcode4.2, xib

This is the thing am trying to do, I have created a form using the .xib file in xcode and am trying to insert and retrieve values from my database table. I have created a database and table using the sqlite manager. Now my thing is I am trying to follow a xcode tutorial and incorporate what I want but its not working

This is my code for viewcontroller.h

```
      #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
     #import <sqlite3.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
 {
       NSString        *databasePath;

   sqlite3 *healthrecords;
 }
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *name;

 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *bloodpressure;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *heartrate;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *sugarlevel;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *status;
 - (IBAction)addinfo:(id)sender;
@end
```

This is my code for viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize name;
 @synthesize bloodpressure;
@synthesize heartrate;
 @synthesize sugarlevel;
 @synthesize status;

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
     {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
   }

    #pragma mark - View lifecycle

     - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
      NSString *docsDir;
      NSArray *dirPaths;

     // Get the documents directory
     dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

     docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

     // Build the path to the database file
     databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir                                stringByAppendingPathComponent:      @"HealthForms.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &healthrecords) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt = 
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HealthRecordsData (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT  NULL UNIQUE, NAME CHAR NOT NULL, Blood Pressure FLOAT NOT NULL, Heart Rate FLOAT NOT NULL, Sugar Level FLOAT NOT NULL, t TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";



        if (sqlite3_exec(healthrecords, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            status.text = @"Failed to create table";
        }

        sqlite3_close(healthrecords);

    } else {
        status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
    }
}


[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

         - (void)viewDidUnload
       {
         [self setName:nil];
          [self setBloodpressure:nil];
        [self setHeartrate:nil];
      [self setSugarlevel:nil];
     [self setStatus:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
      // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
     // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
  }

 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    }

   - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    }

      - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
       {
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        }

       - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
         {
       [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
            }

           - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
      // Return YES for supported orientations
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
           }

              - (IBAction)addinfo:(id)sender {
                  sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

              const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

               if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &healthrecords) == SQLITE_OK)
              {
                     NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO HealthRecordsData (name, Blood Pressure, Heart Rate, Sugar Level) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\")", name.text,     bloodpressure.text, heartrate.text,sugarlevel.text];

            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

               sqlite3_prepare_v2(healthrecords, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
               if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
               {
               status.text = @"info added";
                   name.text = @"";
                    bloodpressure.text = @"";
                    heartrate.text = @"";
                  sugarlevel.text = @"";
                   } else {
                 status.text = @"Failed to add contact";
                }
               sqlite3_finalize(statement);
               sqlite3_close(healthrecords);
               }
              }
              @end
```

The thing is I get build succeeded and I get my app loaded on the simulator but when I press the insert button nothing happens. I am confused and stuck at this point for long now it will be great to get some help. I have checked the DB name , table and also I have connected my xib files with viewcontroller.h properly. Please help thanks